# How to prevent Laravel Image::make converting gif to PNG

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

After uploading image I'm making one thumbnail image its work fine with PNG and jpg but when I upload gif image by default its get converted to PNG, how can I prevent this?

Here is my code

```
$img = Image::make(storage_path().'/app/public/images/'.$this->folderRoot.'/'.$this->imageName);
    $img->resize($this->size, null, function ($constraint) {$constraint->aspectRatio();});
    $img->save('storage/app/public/images/'.$this->folderRoot.$this->storeFolder.$this->resizedImageName,90);
```

experts put light on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving animated gif with image intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513864/saving-animated-gif-with-image-intervention)

Comment: @Dmitry i tried this before but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the second parameter "format" like:

```
Image::make(storage_path().'/app/public/images/'.$this->folderRoot.'/'.$this->imageName, ['format' => 'gif']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `encode()` before you `save()`

```
$originalExtension = pathinfo(storage_path().'/app/public/images/'.$this->folderRoot.'/'.$this->imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$img->encode($originalExtension)->save('storage/app/public/images/'.$this->folderRoot.$this->storeFolder.$this->resizedImageName, 90);
```

Or you try setting `mime`

```
$format= $img->mime();
$img->save('storage/app/public/images/'.$this->folderRoot.$this->storeFolder.$this->resizedImageName, 90, $format);
```